# Vector expected in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Currently I am getting this error.

```
Parameter declaration symmetrize-body-parts should be a vector,
compiling:(braveclojure/core.clj:41:49)
```

**My core.clj file**

```
(ns braveclojure.core
  (:gen-class))

(def asym-hobbit-body-parts [{:name "head" :size 3}
                            {:name "left-eye" :size 1}
                            {:name "left-ear" :size 1}
                            {:name "mouth" :size 1}
                            {:name "nose" :size 1}
                            {:name "neck" :size 2}
                            {:name "left-shoulder" :size 3}
                            {:name "left-upper-arm" :size 3}
                            {:name "chest" :size 10}
                            {:name "back" :size 10}
                            {:name "left-forearm" :size 3}
                            {:name "abdomen" :size 6}
                            {:name "left-kidney" :size 1}
                            {:name "left-hand" :size 2}
                            {:name "left-knee" :size 2}
                            {:name "left-thigh" :size 4}
                            {:name "left-lower-leg" :size 3}
                            {:name "left-achilles" :size 1}
                            {:name "left-foot" :size 2}])

(defn needs-matching-part? [part]
    (re-find #"^left-" (:name part)))

(defn make-matching-part [part] {:name (clojure.string/replace (:name part) #"^left-" "right-")
     :size (:size part)})

(defn symmetrize-body-parts
    "Expects to see a seq of maps which have a :name and :size"
    [asym-body-parts]
    (loop [remaining-asym-parts asym-body-parts
           final-body-parts []]
           (if (empty? remaining-asym-parts)
             final-body-parts
             (let [[part & remaining] remaining-asym-parts
                    final-body-parts (conj final-body-parts part)]
                (if (needs-matching-part? part)
                    (recur remaining (conj final-body-parts (make-matching-part part)))
                    (recur remaining final-body-parts))))))

(defn -main (symmetrize-body-parts asym-hobbit-body-parts))
```

I use `lein run` in the clojure app folder but it is raising the above error. I have switched different things around in regards to the parameter brackets `[]` location for the symmetrize-body-parts function definition from above to below the docstring as well but to no avail. What is going on here?

Following the tutorial from [here](http://www.braveclojure.com/do-things/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```clj
(defn -main [] 
  (symmetrize-body-parts asym-hobbit-body-parts))
```